Rigorous Interpretation of Symbols Used in Helmholtz Equation
$\newcommand{\realset}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\lapop}[1]{\nabla^{2} #1}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
$\newcommand{\shift}[1]{\tau_{#1}}$
Suppose $V$ is a set of points for a scattering object and a point source is located at $\boldsymbol{s} \in \realset^{3}$. Let $f$ the solution for the Helmholtz equation under some boundary condition defined on $V$, say, $\left(Lf\right)\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) = t\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$ for any $\boldsymbol{x} \in \partial V$. My confusion mostly comes from the way the Helmholtz equation is written: for any $\boldsymbol{x} \in \realset^{3} \setminus V$,
\begin{equation*}
\left(\lapop f\right)\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) + k^{2} f\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) = -\delta\left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{s}\right).
\end{equation*}
After some learning of distribution theory, I started to doubt my previous knowledge. Actually $\delta\left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{s}\right)$ is not a rigorous way to write it. We should be use $\shift{\boldsymbol{s}}\delta$ to denote the shift operator applied on a tempered distribution. But that what is correct representation of "for any $\boldsymbol{x} \in \realset^{3} \setminus V$" in distribution theory? Since $\delta$ is not a function, evaluation of it at a point is not the right way to represent the physical problem... Maybe in this case, $\delta$ has a different meaning from the $\delta$ without a boundary? I am thinking  that this $\delta$ may be defined on a different set of test functions defined on $\realset^{3} \setminus V$, rather than on $\realset^{3}$.

It just means to consider both sides of the equation as distributions on $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus V$ (I suppose $V$ is a closed set).

Functionals on a set of test functions on $\mathbb{R}^{3} \setminus V$?

yes. For any open set $U\subset \Bbb{R}^n$, one has a space of test functions $\mathcal{D}(U)$ (smooth, compactly supported functions), and so taking the dual space $\mathcal{D}’(U)$ (i.e the continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{D}(U)$) gives the space of distributions on $U$.

Then some other confusion... $\delta$,  in my understanding, is defined as $\delta f  = f\left(0\right)$ for any test function $f$. What if $f$ does not have $0$ in its domain? :)

For any $U$ and any $p\in U$, you can define the translate of the Dirac delta $\delta_p$ whose value on $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(U)$ is $\delta_p(\phi):=\phi(p)$. If not it doesn’t make sense. Anyway, I suggest you re-read your source carefully, and if they don’t make these assumptions explicit, then fill them in yourself.

Yes, I understand $\delta_{p} = \tau_{p} \delta$. That clarifies my confusion. Thanks!
